# C++ - Properly accessing nested struct in union

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I am working on a project for school, and need to get this structure of code up and working properly.
**PROBLEM:** I need to properly access the union members (h and s), without getting a random chunk of memory data -- and actually get back the number I stored. I do understand how unions work so I am confused why my code is giving me random data and not the number I stored in there.
**NOTE**: I did look for other answers to this problem (as this sounded like a pretty common syntax problem), but the other solutions didn't really fit my situation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct worker {
    enum kind {NOTSALARIED, ISSALRIED};
    bool isSalaried;

    union {
        struct hourly{
            double numberHours;
            double hourlyRate;
        } h; // end of 'hourly' struct
        struct salaried{
            double salaryAmount;
            double bonusAmount;
        } s; // end of 'salaried' struct
    } info; // end of 'info' union
};

/// PROTOTYPE section
worker* getHourly();
worker* getSalaried();
void printWorker(worker);

int main() {
    worker *theWorker; // avoids making another 'worker' object for no reason

    // format code for 'double' values
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    // used string so avoid user entering name with the correct first character
    string choice;
    cout << "(H)ourly or (S)alary? ";
    getline(cin, choice);

    /// LOGIC SECTION: Checks what the user entered
    if(choice == "H" || choice == "h") {
        // get the salary
        theWorker = getHourly();
        // pass in the dereferenced pointer to print out the info
        printWorker(*theWorker);
    }
    if(choice == "S" || choice == "s") {
        // get the salary
        theWorker = getSalaried();
        // pass in the dereferenced pointer to print out the info
        printWorker(*theWorker);
    }

    return 0;
}

 // method that gets the information -- creates a new worker object --     returns a pointer to the object
worker* getHourly() {
    worker newWorker;

    // set the isSalaried equal to false
    newWorker.isSalaried = worker::NOTSALARIED; // equals 0 -- FALSE

    cout << "Enter the number of hours worked: ";
    // take in the hours worked
    cin >> newWorker.info.h.numberHours;

    cout << "Enter the hourly pay rate: ";
    // take in the hourly rate
    cin >> newWorker.info.h.hourlyRate;

    return &newWorker;
}

worker* getSalaried() {
    worker newWorker;

    // set the kind equal to SALARIED
    newWorker.isSalaried = worker::ISSALARIED; // equals 1 -- TRUE

    cout << "Enter the salary amount: ";
    // take in the salary
    cin >> newWorker.info.s.salaryAmount;

    cout << "Enter the bonus amount: ";
    // take in the bonus
    cin >> newWorker.info.s.bonusAmount;

    return &newWorker;
}

void printWorker(worker theWorker) {
    double grossPay;

    // take care of the SALARIED first
    if (theWorker.isSalaried) {
        // add the salary to the bonus amount
        grossPay = (theWorker.info.s.salaryAmount + theWorker.info.s.bonusAmount);

        // print out the info
        cout << "Salaried Worker" << endl;
        // print out the salary
        cout << "Salary: $" << theWorker.info.s.salaryAmount << endl;
        // print out the bonus
        cout << "Bonus: $" << theWorker.info.s.bonusAmount << endl;
    }
    // now, take care of the HOURLY
    if ( !(theWorker.isSalaried) ) {
        // get the product of the number of hours worked and the hourly rate
        grossPay = (theWorker.info.h.numberHours * theWorker.info.h.hourlyRate);

        // print out the info
        cout << "Hourly Worker" << endl;
        // print out the number of hours worked
        cout << "\tHours: " << theWorker.info.h.numberHours << endl;
        // print out the rate
        cout << "\tRate: $" << theWorker.info.h.hourlyRate << endl;
    }

    // print out the last portion here, since this code will be executed for both
    cout << "\t--------" << endl;
    cout << "\tGross Pay: $" << grossPay << endl;
}
```

Comment: `return &newWorker;` - you return address of local variable

Comment: Why did you tag C?

Comment: I tagged C because a C programmer could help in this situation too. As unions and structs are both in C as well. Structs are definitely different, but a C programmer would still be able to help.

Comment: @Nik stop spamming tags.

Comment: I'm not spamming tags. All tags directly correspond to the question at hand. Both are constructs of both C and C++ (C's structs are just a little different) -- not sure why I'm getting flack over this...? I also have 'C++' in the title -- logically pretty easy to figure out it's C++.

Comment: @Nik there is no need to update your question title with the word solved.

Comment: Shoot! I just sneezed. Can I get a dislike for that too? BTW: I've been 'yelled' at before for not doing that... so which is it?

Comment: @PaulRooney is correct in this case. Once you get the hang of all the rules you'll see they make sense. While we're at it, if you properly tag the question you don't need to add the language to the title (though people aren't as strict about that.)

Comment: @Nik I know it seems like that when you enter a new community but that's not the intention. You know its solved because the answer section of the question is in a green square, when shown in the list of questions [see here](https://imgur.com/a/48CWg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the above code on code blocks, and it works, but I am sure that this code is not safe to run every time.
The reason of your problem is: your 2 function

```
worker* getHourly()
{
    worker newWorker;
        ...
        return &newWorker;
}

worker* getSalaried() {
    worker newWorker;
     ...
     return &newWorker;
}
```

In these 2 function you create a local variable from worker, then you returned its address to the caller at main.
since the local variable is removed from memory, after the function terminate, so, the pointer "theWorker" in the main, hold an address at the memory that doesn't belong to you anymore, this may lead to your problem.
you have to make one of two solution:
First one, Keep the function as it is, but in the function, define a pointer instead of variable, and allocate it as dynamic allocation as follow:

```
worker* getHourly()
{
    worker* newWorker;
     newWorker = new (worker)        
     ...
        return newWorker;
}

worker* getSalaried() {
    worker* newWorker;
     newWorker = new (worker);
     ...
     return &newWorker;
}
```

The second one: let the 2 function return a variable instead of address as follow:

```
worker getHourly()
{
    worker newWorker;
     ...
        return newWorker;
}

worker getSalaried() {
    worker newWorker;
     ...
     return &newWorker;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting chunk since in ...

```
worker* getSalaried() {
    worker newWorker;
    ...
    return &newWorker;
}
```

you return the address of a local variable. So the lifetime of `newWorker` ends once `getSalaried` has finished, and accessing an object after his lifetime has ended is undefined behaviour (providing "chunk", for example). To overcome this, you could either return a `worker`-struct itself (not a pointer to it), or you could pass an instance of `worker` to the function such that this can directly write into it.